# What is the efficient and reliable way to upload multiple files in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, file-upload

I need an idea to develop an application in asp.net. The purpose of the application would be to upload multiple files for a particular task.

So how could I upload multiple files at a time having no reliability, scalability and performance issue. In addition to that each file could have some descriptions as well.

Thanks.

Comment: Not sure how can this be answered in a `reasonable way`... :/ There are multiple paths available, for instance get more experience and write a library for yourself. If you don't want to write one from scratch, there are numerous libraries to choose from...

Comment: @walther What could be the possible solutions?

Comment: I have following solutions like; <br/>
1- Upload multiple files Using HTTPModule 
2- Utility- windows service application
3- Colud- DropBox or GoogleDrive etc
4- One by one upload so the user can put some descriptions of the file

Comment: I believe the best idea is to try some libraries/controls made by others, test them to see if they fit your definition and if not, create one yourself. There's no definite answer to the question `what's best`. Every solution, well almost, can be reliable and efficient if you use it the right way in the right situation. The trick is to know your tools to decide what to use for your current needs. We don't know the specifics of your software, we can't do this for you. At least I can't, seems Ashok can :))

Answer (score 3):

Use multiple file upload user control 
this link provide you a multiple file upload user control 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24271/Multiple-File-Upload-User-Control

Comment: I do have such solutions in my mind, but I'm in a confusion what to implement.

Comment: You can upload multiple files using this user control because asp.net simple default file upload control can not upload multiple files at a same time.